# Strophe.js register plugin not working

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

I have Ejabberd server hosted in remote location. And I am trying to register new accounts using Strophe.js register plugin I could not find why this is not working. Below is the code I have written

```
    var connection = new Strophe.Connection("http://ip-address:5222/http-bind");
    var callback = function (status) {
        alert(Strophe.Status.REGISTER); // Returning me 10
        if (status === Strophe.Status.REGISTER) {
            alert("Entered");
            connection.register.fields.username = "hello";
            connection.register.fields.password = "hello";
            connection.register.submit();
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.REGISTERED) {
            alert("registered!");
            connection.authenticate();
        } else if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
            alert("logged in!");
        } else {
            // Sometimes execution entering into this block.
            document.body.innerHTML = (JSON.stringify(status));
        }
    };
    connection.register.connect("localhost", callback);
```

Any extra code to be added to this or any fix I have to do make this work. Please help me on this. Strophe.js documentation is awful.

Comment: I don't know anything about Strophe.js, but is it possible to see the XMPP stanzas being sent and received?  Seeing those would probably identify the problem right away.

Comment: the trick is to use both RAW INPUT AND RAW OUTPUT + CONNECTION STATUS, to determine what is really going on with the server.  please see this code: http://faraxmobile.com/r/afrika/hula3/js/models/connection/ConnectionModel.js

I have to warn you that I'm using backbone.js and JOOP.

Answer (score 2):

In  **strophe.register.js** go to line no 215 and make change as per below code.

```
 /*if (register.length === 0) {
            that._changeConnectStatus(Strophe.Status.REGIFAIL, null);
            return;
        } else */
this.enabled = true;
```

Try above one.

Answer (score 2):

```
var connection = new Strophe.Connection("http://ip-address:5222/http-bind/");
```

Trailing Slash is needed at the end.